# Will Cloud Dataflow throw exceptions when performing autoscaling?

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We are currently using Dataflow to run a streaming job. In that job, we perform datastore transactions of the following form:

```java
Entity task;
Transaction txn = datastore.newTransaction();
try {
  task = txn.get(taskKey);
  update(task);
  txn.put(task);
  txn.commit();
} finally {
  if (txn.isActive()) {
    txn.rollback();
  }
}
```

In the event of scaling up/down, we see a lot of exceptions that activate the `rollback`. This would mean that the transaction is still active and that the `commit` statement was never executed. We do not, however see datastore exceptions in this case.

We suspect that Dataflow cancels the active processing of elements and retries them in the scaled pipeline. This would then throw an unhandled exception and execute the `finally` steps. For some elements this would be *before* the `commit`, which would explain the behaviour.

Also, the exception is maybe not exposed by Dataflow as these are internal ones.

If the above is not the case, it would seem that the transaction implementation is faulty, which we -of course- assume is correct.

Is the reasoning correct? Or is there an other explanation?

Comment: I am not sure if autoscaling causes re-execution though. Generally speaking, Dataflow could re-execute ParDo on an element more than once(machine failures for example may require re-execute functions over failed elements). Having side effect(connecting to remote systems) within ParDo should take this into consideration.

Comment: @RuiWang thanks for your comment! We indeed do take this into consideration by implementing idempotency. However, we would like to understand the source of our exceptions, so that we are confident there are no actual issues. :)

Comment: Hi there @Jonny5, is it okay if you post more of your pipeline code? I'm curious to see how this transaction logic fits in with the rest of the pipeline.